# Line series points the side of bar series instead of in the middle bar series

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3fc

I am using D3 v6.7 and d3fc v15.2.6 with react . Line series points the side of bar series instead of in the middle of bar. How to point line series in the mid of bar?

[image]

I got one solution in d3 .The link has given below:

https://observablehq.com/@d3/bar-line-chart

The following lines do the same work in d3

```
""line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x(d.year) + x.bandwidth() / 2)
    .y(d => y2(d.efficiency))""
```

But I do not understand how to implement in d3fc.

[My project on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-violet-9f745z?file=/src/components/FinancialChart.tsx)